# Running 32bits Aduio on android

Tags: java, c#, android, naudio, cscore

I'm working on streaming the running audio on PC to an android phone in **Real Time**

But my problem is the recorded audio which comes from PC is in 32 bits per sample.
which can't be played on android.

This is my Code for PC in C#:

> Using CSCore library, And i'v tried NAudio too

```
        var wasapiCapture = new WasapiLoopbackCapture();
        wasapiCapture.Initialize();
        var wasapiCaptureSource = new SoundInSource(wasapiCapture);
        WaveFormat waveFormat = wasapiCapture.WaveFormat;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[waveFormat.BytesPerSecond];
        wasapiCaptureSource.DataAvailable += (s, e) =>
        {

            int read = wasapiCaptureSource.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            stream.Write(buffer, 0, read);
            stream.Flush();

        };

        wasapiCapture.Start();
```

My Code for android using java:

```
 int maxJitter = AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize(44100, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);

        AudioTrack audioTrack =new AudioTrack(AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION,44100,1,AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,maxJitter,AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);
        audioTrack.play();
        while ((read = reader.read(bytes)) != -1) {
           audioTrack.write(bytes,0,read);
        }
        audioTrack.stop();
```

This code is running very good when i change WasapiLoopbackCapture to WaveIn and record from Mic. because WaveIn let me change wave format to a suitable one 
Any Suggestion ?

Comment: I finally manged to do it, by the help from this Question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31788741/resample-loopback-capture

Comment: What kind of format output format do you need? Specific samplerate, channels, bps,...?

Comment: This is the format i need,SampleRate=44100 Channels = 1 bps=16
But i'v done it

Comment: https://github.com/filoe/cscore/tree/master/Samples/RecordWithSpecificFormat